# Where is the node_type variable set?

Tags: nodes

Looking at the documentation for the Drupal 8 [html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21html.html.twig/8.2.x) template file, I notice node_type is listed between the available variables for that template file.
Contrary to the other variables available to that template file, thought, node_type is not set from [`template_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/8.2.x) nor [`_template_preprocess_default_variables()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/_template_preprocess_default_variables/8.2.x), which are the functions I expect to set the documented variables for that template file.

What function or method initializes node_type to the bundle of the currently viewed node for html.html.twig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

node_type is set in [`node_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.module/function/node_preprocess_html/8.2.x) from the Node module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for HTML document templates.
 */
function node_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // If on an individual node page, add the node type to body classes.
  if (($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) && $node instanceof NodeInterface) {
    $variables['node_type'] = $node->getType();
  }
}
```